# type 'Future<Stations>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, mobile

API call is triggered by a button press, this button calls AnchoredMapMarkers which should display lat/long pins on the pre-loaded map

Returns `print('step5.1_APICALL');` okay after `async`

Error shows as `type 'Future<Stations>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'`

Any help is greatly appreciated

The API calls and displays in list form fine - I am now trying to extract the lat/long from the Json and plot it on my map SDK

```
class MapMarkerExample{
  
    
 void showAnchoredMapMarkers() { 
  var stations;
       stations = fetchStations(); 
       for (Station stations in stations) {
           GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates = GeoCoordinates (stations.place.location.lat, stations.place.location.lng);
       
           _addCircleMapMarker(geoCoordinates, 0);
           _addPOIMapMarker(geoCoordinates, 1);
           
           } 
        }


  Future<Stations> fetchStations() async {
  print('step5.1_APICALL');
    var client = http.Client();

      final response = await client.get(
      'https://transit.hereapi.com/v8/stations?in=lat,-long&return=transport&apiKey=API_KEY');
   
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Stations.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)); 
    } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load stations');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not awaiting your future. And to make it extra complicated for the compiler, you somehow split declaration and assignment. And reused a variable name.

Fix:

```
Future<void> showAnchoredMapMarkers() async { 
    final stations = await fetchStations();

    for (Station station in stations) {  
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you, error has gone. Only issue is that the map marker isn't showing on the map - no errors registered though

Comment: This is the feedback now  ```_AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.<…>
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: assets/poi.png```

Comment: Well, the error message is clear, isn’t it? You have no asset of that name or maybe you haven’t listed it in your yaml file

Answer (score 1):

you need await

```dart
Future<void> showAnchoredMapMarkers() async {
  var stations = await fetchStations();
  for (Station stations in stations) {
    GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates = GeoCoordinates (stations.place.location.lat, stations.place.location.lng);
    
    _addCircleMapMarker(geoCoordinates, 0);
    _addPOIMapMarker(geoCoordinates, 1);
  } 
}
```